# VBA iterating rows depending on value in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get my VBA script to write of a section of text in order of instance value from another worksheet. I have a section of code that writes out a chunk of text to worksheet A.

```
Dim selectedTest As String
Dim activeCell As Range
Dim outputCell As Range
Dim currentValue As String
Dim activePage As String
Dim row As String
Dim instancecol As String

selectedTest = template.Range("I6, I6").value
Set activeCell = template.Cells.Find(selectedTest + " Data")
Set activeCell = activeCell.Offset(0, 1)
instancecol = Split(activeCell(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
Set activeCell = activeCell.Offset(2, -1)
currentValue = activeCell.value
row = activeCell.row
activePage = template.Range("B" + row)

Set outputCell = json.Range("D26")

outputCell.Activate
outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "name" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + activePage + Chr(34) + ","
Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "instance" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + "1" + Chr(34) + ","
Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "Input" + Chr(34) + ": ["
Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(0, 1)

While Not currentValue = "ENDPARSE"

If Not (activeCell.Offset(0, 1).value = "") Then

    Dim currentPage As String
    Dim referenceType As String
    Dim reference As String
    Dim action As String
    Dim wait As String
    Dim screenshot As String
    Dim instance As String

    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
    outputCell.value = "{"
    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 1)


    row = activeCell.row
    currentPage = template.Range("B" + row)

    If Not (activePage = currentPage) Then
        activePage = currentPage
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(-1, -1)
        outputCell.value = ""
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(-1, 0)
        outputCell.value = "}"
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, -1)
        outputCell.value = "]"
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, -1)
        outputCell.value = "},"
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
        outputCell.value = "{"
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 1)
        outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "name" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + activePage + Chr(34) + ","
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
        outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "instance" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + "1" + Chr(34) + ","
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
        outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "Input" + Chr(34) + ": ["
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 1)
        outputCell.value = "{"
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 1)
    End If

    referenceType = template.Range("C" + row)
    reference = template.Range("A" + row)
    action = template.Range("F" + row)
    wait = template.Range("H" + row)
    screenshot = template.Range("I" + row)
    instance = template.Range(instancecol + row)
    currentValue = activeCell.value

    outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "type" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + referenceType + Chr(34) + ","
    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
    outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "reference" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + reference + Chr(34) + ","
    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
    outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "action" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + action + Chr(34) + ","
    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
    outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "instance" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + instance + Chr(34) + ","
    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
    outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "wait" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + wait + Chr(34) + ","

    If Not (currentValue = "") Then
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
        outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "value" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + currentValue + Chr(34) + ","
    End If

    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, 0)
    outputCell.value = Chr(34) + "screenshot" + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + screenshot + Chr(34)

    Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, -1)
    outputCell.value = "},"

End If

Set activeCell = activeCell.Offset(1, 0)
currentValue = activeCell.value
Wend

outputCell.value = "}"
Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, -1)
outputCell.value = "]"
Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, -1)
outputCell.value = "}"
Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, -1)
outputCell.value = "]"
Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1, -1)
outputCell.value = "}"

Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = json.UsedRange
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(template.Range("I2,I2") + "\\" + template.Range("I3,I3") + ".json", True)
For Each C In dataRange
a.WriteLine (C.value)
Next C
a.Close

template.Activate

End Sub
```

This takes values from worksheet B to write the information in worksheet A. At the moment my output looks like this:

```
{           
"name": "Search",       
"instance": "1",        
"Input": [      
    {   
        "type": "button",
        "reference": "Search",
        "action": "Click",
        "instance": "1",
        "wait": "10",
        "screenshot": "true"
    },  
    {   
        "type": "dropdown",
        "reference": "PostcodeLogic",
        "action": "SelectByText",
        "instance": "2",
        "wait": "10",
        "value": "Is",
        "screenshot": "true"
    },  
    {   
        "type": "text",
        "reference": "PostCodeInput",
        "action": "SendKeys",
        "instance": "3",
        "wait": "10",
        "value": "AL2 4ED",
        "screenshot": "true"
    },  
    {   
        "type": "button",
        "reference": "Search",
        "action": "Click",
        "instance": "5",
        "wait": "10",
        "screenshot": "true"
    },  
    {   
        "type": "link",
        "reference": "ClientName ",
        "action": "Click",
        "instance": "4",
        "wait": "10",
        "screenshot": "true"
    }   
]       
}
```

As you can see all the information i want is there and work correctly. I now need to make it so that it write out the chunk of test in order of `instance`. I have a field called `sequence` that reads then number and puts it into the `instance` field.

Apologies if this is not explained well, still very new to VBA.

Comment: Can you apply a sort on Sequence column before?

Comment: There is a column that has the sequence number. Which is where i get the `instance` value from in each chunk of text. However at the moment it reads the rows top to bottom. I would like it to read depending on the value in that column. e.g row with sequence value 1, then 2, etc.

Comment: So sort the column before your code, then remove the sort.

Comment: It is a table that has 500+ rows. not every row will have a sequence number. And for other parts of the code require certain rows to be in order. if i can get VBA to order it for me would be ideal.

Comment: You'll need to put all the data in a collection (array, collection, dictionary) then write your own sort routine on it.  Could, a workaround, put the data in a sheet, then sort, then do your formatting, so just put the data in a sheet, sort it, then do your code.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246067

Comment: I have this line of code: `If Not (activeCell.Offset(0, 1).value = "") Then` which makes sure it only writes out if there is a value it the sequence column. Is there a way I can have it to say for example run this code if `activeCell.Offset(0, 1).value = "1"` and then rerun this for values of 2 and so on

Comment: Yes, the way you've said with an IF, but you'll need to wrap it in a loop from 1 to the max of the seq #

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, not posted as an answer, just to use the code formatting.  I have my data in A and the seq number in B

```
Sub testing()

Dim OutputCollection As New Collection                  '   For ease
Dim intMaxSeq As Integer
Dim intSeq As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer

intMaxSeq = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("N:N"))

For intSeq = 1 To intMaxSeq

    For intRow = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        If Range("N" & intRow) = intSeq Then
            '   Your code will sit here to build the o/p

            '   Like this example only!!!!!!!!
            sheet("Output").range("a1").value=range("A" & introw).value
            sheet("Output").range("b1").value=range("C" & introw).value
            sheet("Output").range("c1").value=range("J" & introw).value
            '



        End If

    Next intRow

Next intSeq

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added more of my code to the question. i can seem to work out where you put you code to make it work. At the moment the Sequence column is N. The data that is used to populate the chunks of code is from column A,C,F,H,I,K. sorry just getting a bit confused.